# Change scroll direction of webpage on mobile version

Tags: html, css, layout, scroll, scroll-snap

I've build a page with a few sections with videos as background and whenever the user scrolls, there is a scrollsnap to each different section.

However on mobile i would like the user to scroll horizontally instead of verticaly.
I know the trick for scrollsnap is to set type: x mandatory, But to get it actually to work i need to change the layout of my page so that instead of

body = 500vh * 100vw on desktop (there is 5 section of 100vh and 100vw each)

it becomes :

body = 100vh * 500vw on mobile

is there anyway to change the layout in such way with media queries ?

```css
html,body{ margin:0; padding:0; background-color: #232323; }
            
            .text_id {
                color: #fff;
                font-size:calc(12px + 1.8vw);
                font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
                font-weight: 600;
                text-align: center;
            }
            
        .centering_container, .centering_container2, .centering_container3, .centering_container4, .centering_container5 {
              z-index: -1;
              height:100%;
              width:100%;
              overflow:hidden; 
              display: flex;
              justify-content: center;
              align-items: center;
              flex-direction: column;
              position: relative;
            }
            
            #wrapper{
              position: relative;
              height: 100vh;
              overflow: hidden;
              z-index: 3;
            }
            #featured {
              position: absolute;
              z-index: 2;
              width: calc(100vh * (1920 / 1080));    /*  video width / height  */
              height: calc(100vw * (1080 / 1920));   /*  video height / width  */
              min-width: 100%;
              min-height: 100%;
              top: 50%;
              left: 50%;
              transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }
            #wrapper2{
              position: relative;
              height: 100vh;
              overflow: hidden;
              z-index: 2;
            }
            #featured2{
              position: absolute;
              z-index: 3;
              width: calc(100vh * (1620 / 1080));    /*  video width / height  */
              height: calc(100vw * (1080 / 1620));   /*  video height / width  */
              min-width: 100%;
              min-height: 100%;
              top: 50%;
              left: 50%;
              transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }
            #wrapper3 {
              position: relative;
              height: 100vh;
              overflow: hidden;
              z-index: 2;
            }
            #featured3 {
              position: absolute;
              z-index: 2;
              width: calc(100vh * (1920 / 1080));    /*  video width / height  */
              height: calc(100vw * (1080 / 1920));   /*  video height / width  */
              min-width: 100%;
              min-height: 100%;
              top: 50%;
              left: 50%;
              transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }
            #wrapper4 {
              position: relative;
              height: 100vh;
              overflow: hidden;
              z-index: 4;
            }
            #featured4 {
              position: absolute;
              z-index: 2;
              width: calc(100vh * (1920 / 1080));    /*  video width / height  */
              height: calc(100vw * (1080 / 1920));   /*  video height / width  */
              min-width: 100%;
              min-height: 100%;
              top: 50%;
              left: 50%;
              transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }
            
            #wrapper5 {
              position: relative;
              height: 100vh;
              overflow: hidden;
              z-index: 2;
            }
            #featured5 {
              position: absolute;
              z-index: 2;
              width: calc(100vh * (960 / 506));    /*  video width / height  */
              height: calc(100vw * (506 / 960));   /*  video height / width  */
              min-width: 100%;
              min-height: 100%;
              top: 50%;
              left: 50%;
              transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }
            
            video {
              z-index: -2;
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              left: 0;
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
            }
            
            
            
            /******** smooth scroll  scrollsnap********/
            
            .scroll-container {
              width: 100%;
              height: 100vh;
              overflow: auto;
              -webkit-scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
              -ms-scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
              scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
            }
            
            .receveur {
              scroll-snap-align: start;
              scroll-behavior: smooth;
            }
```

```html
<!-- ************************** WHAT I NEED 
            
            
                IN DESKTOP
            
                 ------
                | 100vh|
                | 100vw|
                |      |
                |   ↓  |
                 ------
                 Scrollsnap
                 ------
                | 100vh|
                |100vw |
                |      |
                |   ↓  |
                 ------
                 Scrollsnap
                 ------
                |100vh |
                |100vw |
                |      |
                |   ↓  |
                 ------     
                IN MOBILE
            
                 ------            ------            ------    
                |100vh |          |100vh |          |100vh |
                |100vw |          |100vw |          |100vw |
                |      |Scrollsnap|      |Scrollsnap|      |
                |   →  |      →   |   →  |     →    |  →   |
                |      |          |      |          |      |
                 ------            ------            ------
                 
  ***********--!>
  
  
   
        
<!-- ****************************** FIRST section ********************************* -->

     <div class="scroll-container">
        <div class="receveur receveur-1"></div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="featured">
                <video autoplay="true" muted="true" loop>
                  <source src="style/vid/3_third.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                </video>
                <div class="centering_container">
                    <div class="text_id">
                        <h1 style="line-height:120%;">Section 1</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            



<!-- ****************************** SECOND section ********************************* -->
        <div class="receveur receveur-2" id="arrowscroll"></div>
        <div id="wrapper2">
            <div id="featured2">
                <video autoplay="true" muted="true" loop>
                  <source src="style/vid/1_first.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                </video>
                <div class="centering_container2">
                    <div class="text_id">
                        <h1 style="line-height:120%;">SECTION<br>2<span class="tim">™</span></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


<!-- ***************************** THIRD sectiom  ********************************************* -->


        <div class="receveur receveur-3"></div>
        <div id="wrapper3">
            <div id="featured3">
                <video autoplay="true" muted="true" loop>
                  <source src="style/vid/2_second.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                </video>
                <div class="centering_container3">
                    <div class="text_id">
                        <h1 style="line-height:120%;">Section <br>3</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




<!-- ***************************** FOURTH VIDEO  ********************************************* -->


        <div class="receveur receveur-4"></div>
        <div id="wrapper4">
            <div id="featured4">
                <video autoplay="true" muted="true" loop>
                  <source src="style/vid/5_fifth.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                </video>
                <div class="centering_container4">
                    <div class="text_id">
                        <h1>Section 4</h1>
                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>
  </div>



<!-- ***************************** FIFTH VIDEO  ********************************************* -->


      <div class="receveur receveur-5"></div>
        <div id="wrapper5">
            <div id="featured5">
                <video autoplay="true" muted="true" loop>
                  <source src="style/vid/4_fourth.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                </video>
                <div class="centering_container5">
            <div class="text_id">
              <h1>Section 5</h1>
            </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using flex we can achieve what you need:

I don't know what your breakpoints are but I've put 600px for the demo:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
/* targeting all wrappers - should probably have some kind of class */
div[id^="wrapper"] {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    flex-basis: 100vw;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.scroll-container {
    width: auto;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    -ms-scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}
}
```

Basically, flex (display:flex) on the container forces all the wrappers to line up in a row (flex-direction:row). Then on the wrappers we say you should be 100% of the view's width (flex-basis:100vw) and you cannot be smaller (flex-shrink: 0).

Then we just switch the scroll snap. However, you might want to check scroll snap is supported in what devices you're targeting https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-snap

Comment: "No all hero wears capes" I thank you and salute you Sir, for this fully functionnal solution <3

Answer (score 1):

Hi look at the css I have created,
this might be help to solve your issue

[demo](https://mobile-css-for-horizontal-scorll.stackblitz.io/) : please not that this would only work when on mobile width lower than 1024px. It is the media query I have used and you can change it as you please.

[repo link to stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mobile-css-for-horizontal-scorll?file=styles.css)

CSS code

```
div{
  background-color: beige;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.child{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    .parent{
      display: block;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
   
    .child{
      height: 100%;
      width: 100vh;
      display:inline-block;
    }
}
```

HTML Code

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">1st video</div>
    <div class="child">2nd video</div>
    <div class="child">3rd video</div>
    <div class="child">4th video</div>
    <div class="child">5th video</div>
</div>
```

Meta tag <-- !IMPORTANT

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, time and effort. I really appreciate it ! However in your Repo/Demo each sections are not 100vw/100% width but seems to be a bit more

Comment: @Mathi haha lol its because I have used border:1px solid; for more clarity. I have removed it. You can check now :)

Comment: Thanks mate ;D it's another cool way to do it, wish i could give 2 bounties as you also deserve it. However downvoting because i didn't validate your answer is a bit rude in my opinion but I do understand that you're disappointed with the bounty situation given the fact that you've put effort

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use the `@media` rule in CSS as exampled below:

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    html, body {
        // insert code here
    }
    .text_id {
        // insert code here
    }
}
```

So essentially you would find the max-width of any mobile devices that your website may be used on and set CSS rules for when the condition is met (when using the `max-width` condition for example it will activate for all code thinner than specified width). You may need to use `!important` at the end of some lines to ensure it isn't overwritten by something else in your code.

Comment: Yes i know about the @media rules :), What i am asking for is the content to put inside. How to change the layout of my body so that it doesn't take height but width as the user navigates

Comment: There are lots of different approaches you could take. The one most recommended by industry would be flex-boxes, I personally use `float: left` on all elements I need to be in a row and/or `display: inline-block` to ensure that all the elements line up in a row. I would then change on the `html, body` to set `overflow-x: scroll` and I believe that should be most of the things you need? Easiest way is probably flex-boxes though, W3schools will give lots of good info on it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However didnt work with inline block nor overflow-x: scroll.  I tried with flexbox but didnt get any result. I'll give it another try though